# SQL Getting the lowest variable from a one to many relationship

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables set up right now (Jobs and Bids).  They're tied together by job_id, which is unique in the Jobs table, but not in Bids.  Also in the Jobs table, is location information.  What i need to do is get the lowest bids for each city in the jobs table.

Essentially i need to grab each DISTINCT city and get all the jobs in that city, then grab all the bids for the jobs, compare them and grab the lowest out of all of those.

I've been trying to do it in SQL, but would be ok to use foreach loops in php as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables, then `GROUP BY` city:

```
SELECT j.city 
    , MIN(b.amount) AS minimum_bid
FROM 
    Jobs AS j
  JOIN                          --- LEFT JOIN if you want cities 
    Bids AS b                   --- without any bid, too
      ON b.job_id = j.job_id
GROUP BY j.city
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is

```
  SELECT MIN(bids_field) 
    FROM jobs, bids
   WHERE jobs.job_id = bids.job_id 
GROUP BY location
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

```sql
SELECT jobs.city, MIN(bids.bid_amount) 
FROM jobs 
LEFT JOIN bids ON bids.job_id = jobs.job_id 
GROUP BY jobs.city;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to find out what the minimum bid amount is, then filter based on that.

```
select b.*
from   job j
join   bid b
on     b.job_id = j.job_id
where  b.amount = 
       (
       select  min(b2.amount) 
       from    bid b2 
       where   b2.job_id = b.job_id
       )
```